# Why does this UITabBarItem image switching code work on iOS 7 but not iOS 7.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios7

This is inside of my AppDelegate.m file. This code worked perfectly on iOS 7. A `UITabBarItem` would be selected, and the one that was selected had it's image changed to a "pressed" image while the other images would change back.

Now the code doesn't work AT ALL in iOS 7.1. Strange. Anyone have any ideas why?

7.0 (notice that the Setting image is changed properly to be filled with white):

[image]

7.1 (notice there is no fill with white on Settings):

[image]

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (IS_IOS7_AND_UP)
    {
        NSLog(@"%d", (int)tabBarController.selectedIndex);

        UITabBarItem *tbi = (UITabBarItem *)(tabBarController.tabBar.items)[tabBarController.selectedIndex];
        UITabBarItem *tb2 = (UITabBarItem *)(tabBarController.tabBar.items)[2];
        UITabBarItem *tb3 = (UITabBarItem *)(tabBarController.tabBar.items)[3];
        UITabBarItem *tb4;

        if ([tabBarController.tabBar.items count] > 4)
            tb4 = (UITabBarItem *)(tabBarController.tabBar.items)[4];


        switch (tabBarController.selectedIndex) {
                case 0:

                    tb2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-icon-ios7"];
                    tb3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"help-icon-ios7"];
                    break;

                case 1:

                    tb2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-icon-ios7"];
                    tb3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"help-icon-ios7"];
                    break;

                case 2:

                    tbi.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-icon-ios7-pressed"];
                    tb3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"help-icon-ios7"];
                    break;

                case 3:

                    tbi.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"help-icon-ios7-pressed"];
                    tb2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-icon-ios7"];
                    break;

                case 4:

                    tb2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-icon-ios7"];
                    tb3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"help-icon-ios7"];
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: how is your IS_IOS7_AND_UP macro defined?

Comment: Why not just use the selectedImage property of UITabBarItem?

Comment: @bjtitus - Unaware of that property actually... I will look into it.

Comment: @Flexicoder - It goes into the if statement just fine. `#define IS_IOS7_AND_UP ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7.0)`

Comment: @bjtitus is correct, it turns out that with iOS7.1 if you want to set the tab bar icon manually in the code, you need to set tabBarItem.selectedImage separately, whereas in <iOS7.1 it seemed enough to just set tabBarItem.image for both selected and non-selected state.

Answer (score 0):

**bjtitus** in the comments correctly answered it for me. I am using the following code now instead (at the creation of the tab bar rather than on the delegate), which fixed the issue:

```
UITabBarItem *tb0 = (UITabBarItem *)(tabController.tabBar.items)[0]; //main
UITabBarItem *tb1 = (UITabBarItem *)(tabController.tabBar.items)[1]; //wishlist
UITabBarItem *tb2 = (UITabBarItem *)(tabController.tabBar.items)[2];
UITabBarItem *tb3 = (UITabBarItem *)(tabController.tabBar.items)[3];
UITabBarItem *tb4;

if ([tabController.tabBar.items count] > 4)
    tb4 = (UITabBarItem *)(tabController.tabBar.items)[4];

if ([[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"MultiApp"] boolValue])
{
    tb2.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-icon-ios7-pressed"];
    tb3.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"appswitch-tab-ios7-pressed"];
    tb4.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"help-icon-ios7-pressed"];
}
else
{
    tb2.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-icon-ios7-pressed"];
    tb3.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"help-icon-ios7-pressed"];
}
```